# How to find objects by geographic location?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

In Firebase 2.0 we had access to geo queries using Geofire 2.0. How do we accomplish geo queries with Firebase 3.0? Are there any plans for updating Geofire?

Answer (score 1):

[Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) for web and Android have been upgraded for the latest Firebase releases. As far as I know GeoFire for Objective-C will continue to work too.

- [GeoFire for JavaScript](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js)
- [GeoFire for Objective-C](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc)
- [GeoFire for Java](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java)

If you're having problems making it work, share the minimal code that reproduces the problem.